# PDFAnnotationText is not displaying pop-up on 10.12

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, annotations, macos-sierra, pdf-annotations

`PDFAnnotationText` is not showing pop-up on macOS sierra 10.12.1 Beta (16B2548a). `PDFAnnotationText` is deprecated on 10.12 but new APIs are not drawing annotations.

Old APIs:

```
// display the PDF document
    [m_pdfView setDocument: [self pdfDocument]];

- (PDFDocument *)pdfDocument {
    // create a page

    PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/test/Downloads/Eticket.pdf"]];
    PDFAnnotationText* result = [[PDFAnnotationText alloc] initWithBounds:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 40, 40)];
    result.color = [NSColor redColor];
    result.contents = @"Hello";
    result.iconType = kPDFTextAnnotationIconNote;
    // add it to the PDF document
    [[document pageAtIndex:0] addAnnotation:result];
    return document;
}
```

10.12 New APIs:

```
- (PDFDocument *)pdfDocument {
    // create a page
    PDFDocument *document = [[PDFDocument alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/test/Downloads/Eticket.pdf"]];

    NSMutableDictionary *popupDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [popupDictionary setObject:@"/Popup" forKey:kPDFAnnotationKey_Subtype];
    [popupDictionary setObject:[NSColor redColor] forKey:kPDFAnnotationKey_Color];
    [popupDictionary setObject:@"Hello" forKey:kPDFAnnotationKey_Contents];

    NSValue *rectValue = [NSValue valueWithRect:NSMakeRect(100, 100, 40, 40)];
    [popupDictionary setObject:rectValue forKey:kPDFAnnotationKey_Rect];

    PDFAnnotation *textAnnotation = [[PDFAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary: popupDictionary forPage: [document pageAtIndex:0]];
    [[document pageAtIndex:0] addAnnotation:textAnnotation];    // add it to the PDF document
    return document;
}
```

I am using Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a). Can anyone please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create a simple black string annotation like this (in Swift 3):

```
let document = pdfView!.document
let page = document!.page(at:0)
let pageBounds = page!.bounds(for: PDFDisplayBox.artBox)
let annotation = PDFAnnotation()
annotation.setValue("/FreeText", forAnnotationKey: kPDFAnnotationKey_Subtype)
annotation.setValue("HELLO WORLD", forAnnotationKey: kPDFAnnotationKey_Contents)
annotation.setValue(NSColor.clear, forAnnotationKey: kPDFAnnotationKey_Color)
annotation.bounds = NSRect(x:10, y:pageBounds.height-50, width:400, height:40)
page!.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

It's using /FreeText, but maybe it will help you if you experiment with the values. Still could not figure out how to change the color of the text.